# MvxTrace output in WPF project

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm not seeing any MvxTrace output in my WPF project.  I'm using the default project template created by NuGet.

Is there anything special that must be done or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default WPF project provides debug output via [MvxDebugTrace](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf/Platform/MvxDebugTrace.cs)

For Release assemblies (such as those included in Nuget) this obviously does nothing.

If you want to link to the release assemblies but use Debug output, then you can do so by implementing `IMvxTrace` and by providing your implementation during setup - you'll need to override `protected abstract IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace();` - in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Platform/MvxSetup.cs#L25

Comment: Aside> I've thought about this before... really can't decide if it's a bug or a feature...  maybe now that NuGet is used so widely, it's something that needs revisiting...

Comment: Logged as https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/275 - will think about it for a while before doing anything