# Debug plugin in MvvmCross

Tags: android, windows-runtime, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm using Monodroid and MvvmCross v3 on a Windows 8 and Android app. I Have a custom plugin and I want to debug it with breakpoints. In the Windows 8 app I can debug my plugin with breakpoint but I can't do it with Android.

So I Tried to use MvxTrace.trace() method but it doesn't work in plugins (Windows 8 & Android).

So how can I debug my custom plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MonoDroid PCL debugging has finally been fixed and apparently released on Alpha - see:

- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8209
- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9759

Mvx.Trace does work in Android, including with release binaries.

For Trace in WiNRT, using the release binaries (eg from Nuget) then you can override the trace provider

- see [MvxTrace output in WPF project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618720/mvxtrace-output-in-wpf-project)

Comment: Ok thanks, 
In android where the trace is displayed ?
I see  Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' but I can't find it and I have nothing in the Android debug monitor too.